# PHP Error in Browser

Tags: php

I am having trouble with this piece of code below. Whenever I run this file from browser it shows me the same code `load_file($target_url); foreach($html->find(‘a’) as $link){ echo $link->href."
"; } ?>` on the browser and not the desired result. I am working on a website using xampp. Php is also properly configured.

```
<?php
 include_once('/simple.php');

 $target_url = "http://www.example.com/";
 $html = new simple_html_dom();
 $html->load_file($target_url);
 foreach($html->find(‘a’) as $link){
 echo $link->href."<br />";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Do you have some other PHP files that work fine? Also - take a look into simple.php Possibly there is something wrong with it. Maybe you can post its code here too. From what I see here, everything should be fine if PHP is configured correctly.

Comment: make sure that extension of your file is .php and How are you opening php tag ? Are you sure you are using <?php , not <?  ?

Comment: Are you simply opening the file by pointing your browser at it as a file, or by using a http://localhost/... URL?

Comment: I am sure that the extension is .php

Comment: @MarkBaker by using localhost

Comment: try to set `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the beginnign of that file and see if it will return some errors

Comment: (off topic, because it's not related to the problem in the question): `find(‘a’)` --> this code won't work as shown. The `a` has invalid quote characters around it. They look like they've been converted to curly quotes by a program like Outlook or Word. You should using avoid programs like this to write code because of stuff like this. Use a programmer's text editor or an IDE.

Comment: You mention that PHP is configured properly. Are you certain of that? Do you have any other PHP programs that are working on the same server? Is there something specific about this program, or does it do the same with any PHP code you throw at it?

Comment: @SDC this may be very on topic instead! What if the dash has been changed to another char by Word as it usually does? It doesn't look like that in the code, but maybe the saved file is different... And maybe saving a unicode char to an ascii text file outputs a "?" instead. And ? plus > equals ?>

Comment: @FrancescoMM - if that's the case, then OUCH OUCH OUCH! that's nasty. And difficult to debug. The scary thing is, it does sound very plausible. There definitely a lesson in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it seems like the PHP parser interprets the -> in $html->load_file( as if it should close PHP parsing, thus showing you the rest of the code as HTML.

it interprets -> as if it was a ?>

The server is probably misconfigured, or some strange option is in effect.

Other PHP files may work fine if they do not contain -> so if not using objects

If they are allowed on your server, you could try alternative syntax:

```
<script language="php">  
echo "This is HTML script tags.";  
</script>
```

Or ASP style syntax

```
<%   
echo 'This is ASP like style';  
%>
```

Although ugly it might solve your problem

Comment: @yesboy If they are allowed, you could try alternative syntax: 
<script language="php">  
echo "This is HTML script tags.";  
</script> 
  
Or ASP style syntax
<%   
echo 'This is ASP like style';  
%>

Answer (score 0):

PHP or your server is not properly configured because instead of executing the code, it is simply outputting it to the browser.

The reason you only see the `load_file()` code onwards, is because the browser interprets the `>` on that line as a closing HTML tag. If you view->source in your browser, you'll see the full code.

Comment: Does this file have an extension other than `.php`?

Comment: @yesboy just rename the file to have a `.php` extension. if you're having trouble changing the extension, just do a `Save As` and call it `something.php`.

Comment: @yesbot I doubt `/simple.php` is the correct path unless it is in the root of your file system. Although fixing that won't make the code execute.

Answer (score 0):

The curly quotes! The curly quotes!

They show the file has been "treated" by the wrong program (Word???), so there is another char that gets modified usually by those nasty softwares, and it is the **DASH** (-)!
Your dash in $html->load is probably not a real dash "-" but some similar looking charachter like the long dash "—".
Look at the difference:

```
----------
real dashes -

––––––––––
alternate dash –
```

For some reason some parser (ftp?webserver?php?) gets confused by this unexpected char, and outputs a ? instead!

And this ? near the > gives a ?> that closes PHP!!!

Rewrite your file using a proper editor, just delete the dashes and write them again and it will work.